# How to have a equation (Matrix) in Sans-Serif font?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

This is a follow up question from [Sans-Serif font in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537872/is-it-possible-only-have-one-paragraph-of-font-written-in-sans-serif-font)

I am using this `\usepackage{helvet}` for my entire writing in Overleaf.
However, for a matrix symbol M, I want to use `Sans-serif font` which I also want a small paragraph using Sans-serif font.

So, I put: `renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`
But it changes the whole entire typing to Sans-serif, which I do not want.

So, I uses:

```
`{\sffamily Text in sans-serif...}` ... normal text
```

will get Sans-serif font in text.

How about in the equation?

```
text {\sffamily A}$\boldsymbol{v}$ $=$ $\lambda$$\boldsymbol{v}$.

\begin{equation}
{\sffamily A}\boldsymbol{v}=\lambda \boldsymbol{v}.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want **all** math to be in sans serif?  Or just the **M**?  Or for any "matrix" symbol?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Nope. I just want my matrix `A` in sans serif font which is only for matric, vector.

Comment: You can use `\mathsf{A}`.  Other options would include `\mathbb{A}`.  The latter requires `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes. Thanks. it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to access sans serif in math mode for the odd symbol here and there is by way of `\mathsf{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily Text in sans-serif...} ... normal text

will get Sans-serif font in text.

How about in the equation?

text $\mathsf{A}\boldsymbol{v}=\lambda\boldsymbol{v}$.

\begin{equation}
\mathsf{A}\boldsymbol{v}=\lambda \boldsymbol{v}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I mentioned in the comment, an alternative (with the `amssymb` package) is `\mathbb{A}`:

[image]